# Calculate the integral of a 2 form

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

I am trying to compute the integral
$$
\int\int_{S}\frac{1}{x}dy\wedge dz+\frac{1}{y}dz\wedge dx+\frac{1}{z}dx\wedge dy
$$
over an ellipsoid given by
$$
\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}=1.
$$

The way I tried to do it was by using the divergence theorem. For $F:=<\frac{1}{x},\frac{1}{y},\frac{1}{z}>$,
$$
\int\int_{S}\frac{1}{x}dy\wedge dz+\frac{1}{y}dz\wedge dx+\frac{1}{z}dx\wedge dy=\int\int_{S}F\cdot dS=\int\int\int_{D}\nabla\cdot F dV.
$$
Then $\nabla\cdot F=-(\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{y^2}+\frac{1}{z^2})$ so
$$
\int\int\int_{D}\nabla\cdot F dV=-\int\int\int_{D}(\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{y^2}+\frac{1}{z^2})dV.
$$
Finally I changed to spherical coordinates by substituting $x=a\rho\cos\theta\sin\phi$,$y=b\rho\sin\theta\sin\phi$,$z=c\rho\cos\phi$ to get
$$
-\int\int\int_{D}(\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{y^2}+\frac{1}{z^2})dV\\
=-abc\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{1}(\frac{1}{a^2\rho^2\cos^2\theta\sin^2\phi}+\frac{1}{b^2\rho^2\sin^2\theta\sin^2\phi}+\frac{1}{c^2\rho^2\cos^2\phi})\rho^2\sin\phi d\rho d\theta d\phi\\
=-abc\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{1}(\frac{1}{a^2\cos^2\theta\sin\phi}+\frac{1}{b^2\sin^2\theta\sin\phi}+\frac{\sin\phi}{c^2\cos^2\phi}) d\rho d\theta d\phi.
$$
I plugged the last integral into Maple to find that the integral was divergent. Did I do something wrong or is that what I am supposed to get? If its correct, how can the integral over a bounded surface be infinite... Sorry my multivariable is a little rusty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot apply divergence theorem directly because $\nabla \cdot F$ has singularity at the origin.

Here is an alternative way: Let $G : S^{2} \to S : (x, y, z) \to (ax, by, cz)$ be diffeomorphism. If $\omega$ denotes the 2-form we are integrating, then

$$G^{*}\omega = \frac{bc}{ax} dy \wedge dz + \frac{ca}{by} dz \wedge dx + \frac{ab}{cz} dx \wedge dy $$

is a 2-form on the unit sphere $S^{2}$ and

$$ \int_{S} \omega = \int_{S^{2}} G^{*}\omega. $$

In classical notation, this reduces to

$$ \int_{S^{2}} G^{*}\omega
= \int_{S^{2}} \left( \frac{bc}{ax}, \frac{ca}{by}, \frac{ab}{cz} \right) \cdot (x, y, z) \, d\sigma
= \int_{S^{2}} \left( \frac{bc}{a} + \frac{ca}{b} + \frac{ab}{c} \right) \, d\sigma. $$

Now you would know how to evaluate $\int_{S^{2}} d\sigma$.